Read Data from Excel and insert into Database
I have multiple rows in an excel file but all data in only one column. I have to insert into multiple columns in database. Each dataset comprises of 3 rows.
Eg Excel content
1234
www.google.com
xyz
--(this is end of first set)
9999
www.yahoo.com
AAA
--(this is end of second set)
Database columns
RefCode int,
website_name varchar(50),
pointcode varchar(5)
After reading the excel i want to store the data like below
1234    www.google.com       xyz
9999    www.yahoo.com        AAA
I wrote the code to extract the data but i am stuck on how to insert into multiple columns.
here is the code i have written, can someone help me ?
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.s;

public class ReadExcelFileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        getRowCount();

    }

    public static void getRowCount() throws IOException {
        String exePath = "./input/Trial.xlsx";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=amour;user=sa;password=DB_Password;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int rowCount = 0;

        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(exePath)) {
            XSSFSheet workSheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();

            rowCount = workSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            System.out.println(rowCount);

            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

            Iterator<Row> rows = workSheet.rowIterator();

            while (rows.hasNext()) {

                for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

                    Object cellValue = df.formatCellValue(workSheet.getRow(i).getCell(0));
                    System.out.println(cellValue);
                    i++;

                }

                x = 0;

                System.out.println("End of Set ");

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            // System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


I would separate your spreadsheet and db code. Iterate the rows of the former and push each value onto a Stack. Make that Observable The observer will check if its depth is 3 and will use it to make a batch insert then clear it

I was able to solve this with Arraylist.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ReadExcelFileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        getRowCount();

    }

    public static void getRowCount() throws IOException {
        String exePath = "./input/Trial.xlsx";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=amour;user=sa;password=DB_Password;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
        int i = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int rowCount = 0;
        XSSFRow row;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(exePath)) {
            XSSFSheet workSheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            // XSSFRow row ;
            rowCount = workSheet.getLastRowNum();
            // System.out.println(rowCount);

            System.out.println(workSheet.getLastRowNum());

            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

            Iterator<Row> rows = workSheet.rowIterator();

            for (int y = 0; y <= rowCount; y++) {
                // while (rows.hasNext()) {

                // if (rows != null) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

                        Object cellValue = df.formatCellValue(workSheet.getRow(i).getCell(0));
                        // row = workSheet.getRow(y);
                        list.add((String) cellValue);
                        i++;

                    }

                    // System.out.println("Array Element"+ list.get(0));

                    System.out.println("Array Element" + list.get(0) + list.get(1) + list.get(2));
                    String Sql = "insert into tbl values(" + list.get(0) + "," + "'" + list.get(1) + "'" + "," + "'"
                            + list.get(2) + "'" + ");";

                    System.out.println(Sql);

                    st.executeQuery(Sql);
                    list = null;
                    x = 0;

                    System.out.println("End of Set ");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                // }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Sure, will change it as needed.
